# how to enable serial port(ttyAMA0) communication using "pi serial" in pi3?

Tags: python, serial-port, serial-communication, raspberry-pi3

i want to enable serial port communication in pi 3 using pi serial.
but when i try to open a port like this

test=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200)

it gives me the error "**port already open**".

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 3):

**finally this got work for my pi3 (os: debian jessie)**

please follow these 6 steps carefully.

**Step 1** - 
    Install Raspbian Jessie onto a SD card and boot the Pi when connected to a network Login via terminal or desktop and shell Configure the system with:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Expand filesystem and enable serial on advanced page, exit and reboot.

**Step 2** -this won't necessary if you have jessie new release.
    Update the system with:

```
 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Step 3** -
    Device Tree settings as below:

Add device tree to **/boot/config.txt** to disable the Raspberry Pi 3 bluetooth.

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

**Add at the end of the file**

*if you want to change the blutooth to miniuart port(bad)

```
dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt
```

*if you want to disable the blutooth(good)

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

Exit the editor saving your changes.

**Step 4** - reboot the pi

```
sudo reboot
```

**step 5** -

a)to disable the Serial Console edit the file using

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

remove the word phase "`console=serial0,115200`" or "`console=ttyAMA0,115200`"

Exit and save your changes

b)to Enable the Serial Console edit the file using

```
sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
```

Change the file to the following:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=serial0(or ttyAMA0),115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

Exit and save your changes

**Step 6** - reboot the pi

```
sudo reboot

 -----------------**that's all,have fun**-------------------------------
```

Comment: So `ttyAMA0` is another device !

Comment: ttyAMA0 is not a device. it is a default port number assigned by the pi os to connect to serial ports in raspberry pi.